# Is Socket io client working in flutter background to implement custom notifications?

Tags: flutter, socket.io, flutter-notification, flutter-background

I have flutter project for chat - like WhatsApp- I'm using node.js with socket in server and using socket_io_client in the app, everything works good, but if the app is closed the socket doesn't work, now I want to use notifications in the app, I'm using flutter_local_notification and to let it works in background I used flutter_background, I tested this with scheduled notifications and everything was working even the app is closed, then I tried to listen to socket and show notification when any message received and everything worked good when the app is open only. I put the socket in the background but it's not working while there is no error appears.